# Why the docker-compose.yml environment overrides the .env file content?

Tags: debian, environment-variables, node.js

I have a docker container that is set up using `docker-compose.yml` and I introduce a couple of environment variables in it:

```
        environment:
            - AUTH_SECRET=some_secret
```

Then I have these values in my `.env` file:

```
AUTH_SECRET=another_secret
```

The problem is that in my application which is a Qwik app, the `.env` file does not override the `docker-compose.yml`.

One would expect the **more specific** project to override the **less specific, more general** OS.

This is my code:

```
import { serverAuth$ } from '@builder.io/qwik-auth'
import type { Provider } from '@auth/core/providers'
import Keycloak from '@auth/core/providers/keycloak'

export const { onRequest, useAuthSession, useAuthSignin, useAuthSignout } = serverAuth$(
    ({ env }) => ({
        secret: env.get("AUTH_SECRET"),
        trustHost: true,
        callbacks: {
            async session({
                session, 
                token,
            }){
                session.user.guid = token.sub
                return session
            }
        },
        providers: [
            Keycloak({
                clientId: 'Site',
                clientSecret: env.get('KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET') as string,
                issuer: env.get('KEYCLOAK_ISSUER') as string
            }),
        ] as Provider[],
    })
);
```

In my code, I get `some_scerent`, instead of `another_secret`.

Is this behavior the normal way? How can I override system-wide environment variables in my specific application?

Answer (score 0):

The documented precedence for environment variables in Docker Compose is this (mostly copied from [Environment variables precedence in Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/envvars-precedence/)):

1. Set using `docker compose run -e` on the command line.
2. Substituted from your shell.
3. Set using the `environment` attribute in the compose file.
4. Use of the `--env-file` argument on the command line.
5. Use of the `env_file` attribute in the compose file.
6. Set using an `.env` file placed at base of your project directory.
7. Set in a container image in the `ENV` directive. Having any `ARG` or `ENV` setting in a `Dockerfile` evaluates only if there is no Docker Compose entry for `environment`, `env_file` or `run --env`.

This means the environment variables you set with `environment` in the compose file will override any variables with the same names in the `.env` file.

Note also that you can use multiple compose files, with the ones specified later on the command line overriding the ones specified earlier. So the thought is that the `.env` file contains the most generic values (well, the `Dockerfile` may contain even more generic values) that you later override in one or several compose files.  These more specific values could also be overridden (e.g., for one-off deployments or tests) by giving new values on the command line.